# Only getting reoccuring singular response with C++ grading program

Tags: c++

Hello I am having a very simple issue with a program ive written for an exercise from a C++ tutorial site. The exercise asks to write a program where you enter a number then it spits out your grade i.e. 0-59 is an F, 60-69 is a D etc...

```
 #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main (){
  unsigned int x;

  cout << "enter your grade";
  cin >> x;

  if (x < 0){
    cout << "cannot have grade less than 0";
  }
  
  else if (x == 100){
    cout << "Congrats";
  }

  else if (0 <= x <= 59){
    cout << "your grade is " << "F";
  }
  else if (60 <= x <= 69){
    cout << "your grade is " << "D";
  }
  
  return 0;
}
```

whenever I run the program, no matter what number I put in it only responds with the letter grade F (even if I put a negative number). Ive been messing around with it for a couple of hours. Still get the same response .

Comment: `0 <= x <= 59` does not work in C++ the way it does in Python.

Comment: `0 <= x <= 59` does not work in C++.  You have to use `0 <= x && x <= 59`.

Comment: You made `x` unsigned so `x < 0` can never be true. Your compiler should be warning you about this redundant code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This condition:

```
if (0 <= x <= 59)
```

is not correct. It evaluates to:

```
if ((0 <= x) <= 59)
```

which is always true. Since `x` is `unsigned` and cannot be negative `x <= 0` will always be true. Even if it were signed, the result would be either `0 <= 59` or `1 <= 59`, both of which are true.

Instead, you need to do:

```
if (0 <= x && x <= 59)
```

Or simply:

```
if (x <= 59)
```

since `x` cannot be negative. In fact all comparisons of `x` against 0 are redundant.